# How to rewrite the method of a class in my module when another method of the same class is rewritten in another?

Tags: sales-order, invoice, pdf

In  `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php` , there is  `protected function _drawHeader()` , which I want to rewrite in my module. I have tried both Model Class rewrite and Plugin rewrite. Plugin does not work because it is a protected method.

The other module  `app\code\Fooman\PrintOrderPdf\Model\Pdf\Order.php`  is rewriting `public function getPdf()`.

Please advise what I should do, copy-paste the `Fooman\PrintOrderPdf` code in my module and add my rewrite, or is there a way to do it without touching the `Fooman\PrintOrderPdf`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, add you code here... for better understanding...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could deal with this using `sequence` in your **module.xml** file

```
<module name="YOUR MODULE" setup_version="XXX">
    <sequence>
        <module name="THIS OTHER MODULE WILL LOAD FIRST"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

And then, you'd rewrite first loaded module class, instead of original class (not tested, maybe rewriting original would work just with the `sequence` change)